# In IOS which is the right way to configure the AWS Cocoa Pod project in subProject which is framework ?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xcode6

Currently I am working in IOS workspace that contain Main project and other subproject which all are framework.
And now I want to configure the AWS POD to one of the subproject which is framework.
Please help me to find the right way to configure the AWS POD.

Thanks

Comment: [CocoaPods Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) should help you understand how to configure `Podfile`. You should share your exact Xcode workspace/project structure and `Podfile`.

Comment: Thanks @Yosuke
I am working on complex structure as below

   ' Workspace
           MainProject
                      Project->Framework1
                      Project->Framework2
                      Project->Framework3
          Pod'

I wanted to access this pod file in Project-> framework3 but I should not.
Please help me to access pod files in Project-> framework3.

Comment: It's still not clear with your workspace structure, but it may be way easier to just use frameworks downloaded from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all supporting me to finding the answer.

Actually I am creating the complex structure,Before I have added all the subProject inside the Main Project in workspace means Workspace contains 2 project **Main Project** and **POD Project**.

My target is to access the POD file in subProject for that I have remove all the Subproject form the MainProject and added to workspace as simple as it and now I am able to access the pod file to sub projects project.